# How do I create an app bundle to publish app on Google Play Store?

Tags: react-native, android-app-bundle, app-bundle

I have created a react native app for the first time. To publish the app, I have to create an app bundle(.aab).

How do I create an **app bundle**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you do to generate an AAB bundle file.

```
cd android
./gradlew bundleRelease
```

Look at [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android) for pre-requisites. To extract an APK out of the bundle and test it on a device before upload then use the [bundletool](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool) from Google.

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly! I did follow these steps, but there was an error saying `FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.` then 
`Task 'bundleRelease' not found in root project`.

Comment: What version of React native are you using?

Comment: React-native version - 1.0.0

Comment: @Shreyashi There is no version 1.0.0 of react-native, please look at your package.json and let me know.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I checked it via terminal and the version is 7.9.0

Comment: Again you are wrong. See it in your package.json not in terminal.

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started - there is no version 7.9.0 there

Comment: The version is shown as 0.64.1. I hope that it is correct.

Comment: Run ./gradlew tasks inside the Android folder to see what all tasks get listed. bundleRelease should be one among them.

Comment: I did run ./gradlew task, but I could not find bundleRelease.

Comment: you will see bundle only, Release is the variant.